# How do I add a left bar button without overriding the natural back button?

Tags: swift, swift2, uinavigationbar

I have a project that uses UIViewControllers embedded in navigation view controllers, so the back button is automatically set up for me whenever I segue into any detail of my tableviews.

Now I want to add an Edit button beside the back button. I've already put an Unassign button on the right side, and since the word "Unassign" is quite long, I'd rather fit the Edit button beside the back button on the left side.

I know I can programmatically add bar buttons with `navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = editButton` but that overrides the back button.

I've also tried appending the editButton to the `navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems` array, but that doesn't work too (since the leftBarButtonItems array isn't set in the first place).

My next approach was to find the back button and manually add it to the leftBarButtonItems array, so I tried using `navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem!, editButton]`, but that only adds a space between the editButton and the left side. No back button.

How do I add in a left bar button while leaving the back button untouched? Is there a more elegant way than manually coding a new back button with `self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)` and adding it to the leftBarButtonItems array?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

By default, the `leftItemsSupplementBackButton` property is `false`. In this case,
 the back button is not drawn and the left item or items replace it. If you
 would like the left items to appear in addition to the back button (as opposed to instead of it) set `leftItemsSupplementBackButton` to `true`.

```
@property(nonatomic) BOOL leftItemsSupplementBackButton
```

you can use something like this

```
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = editButton
//or
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [editButton]

self.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
```

Comment: OH YES THANK YOU!! Perfect answer, exactly what I was looking for. Spent way too much time Googling and getting nowhere XD

Comment: When you struggle with something and you find exactly the answer that fits your needs... in one line, no ugly workaround , no hesitation , just a holy perfect little boolean. 
That day you are so happy to be a developper, you love your work.. ad it's friday. Thank you ♥

Comment: in case someone needs to hide a leftBarButtonItem in the next child screens of the nav controller, you can do this in `viewWillAppear`: `if navigationController?.viewControllers.count ?? 0 > 1` then `navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil` else `navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = makeYourButton()`

Answer (score 4):

These two lines with do the trick. Set `leftItemSupplementBackButton` to true, and then add `leftBarButtonsItems`.

```
self.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [barButton]
```

Comment: pay attention, if you try to "append" new button to leftBarButtonItems - it's doesn't work